# Optional sampling theorem with possibly infinite stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

I have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and assume that $(M_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$ is a martingale on this space satisfying $M_n\geq0$ for all $n\geq1$.

I also have two stopping times $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$, with $\sigma_1 \leq \sigma_2$. These stopping times have positive probability of being infinite.

The optional stopping theorem cannot be applied directly, but I would like to like to show that
$$
 E(M_{\sigma_2} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1})
 =
 M_{\sigma_1 } \qquad \text{a.s.}
$$
What I know is that 
$(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n}, \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_2 \wedge n})$ is also a martingale and that $(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n})$ is uniformly integrable. I have applied to the optional sampling theorem to the martingale
$(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n}, \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_2 \wedge n})$
to conclude that
$$
E(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1 \wedge n})
=
M_{\sigma_1 \wedge n} \qquad \text{a.s.}
$$
I feel I am close to the result. How can I take the above expression "to the limit"? My problem is that I do not know how to tackle the minimum operator in the filtration.

What I also know is that $M_{\sigma_2}$ closes the martingale 
$(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n}, \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_2 \wedge n})$, i.e. 
$E(M_{\sigma_2} \mid \mathcal{F}_n) = M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n}$ because $(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n})$ is uniformly integrable... but I am not sure how to proceed. This question is part of a bigger assignment I am doing, but I think there are enough assumptions here to conclude the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the optional stopping theorem, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}) = M_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}$$

for any $k \leq n$. Since $M_{\sigma_2 \wedge n}$ converges to $M_{\sigma_2}$ in $L^1$ as $n \to \infty$, this implies

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{\sigma_2} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}) = M_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}. \tag{1}$$

Now we can apply Lévy's convergence theorem to conclude

$$\begin{align*} M_{\sigma_1} = \lim_{k \to \infty} M_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}  &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(M_{\sigma_2} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1 \wedge k}) \stackrel{\text{Lévy}}{=} \mathbb{E}(M_{\sigma_2} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\sigma_1}). \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you, saz, this helped me solve my problem, the minimum really did confuse me. If anyone in the future sees this and would like references to the results used, then look at Theorem 5.4.7(2) and Theorem 5.4.8 in these [notes](http://www.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf). Cheers!